# Detailed logging of OS X

Tags: mac-osx, logging

The company I work at is going from small business to medium along with new HR requirements.

We mainly have OS X workstations. I'd like a solution where all of these workstations log to a local server on our network to include timestamped entries for;

- Applications opened
- Sites visited
- Files opened
- Files deleted

Are there any off-the-shelf solutions for this or would I be better off developing this from scratch?

Comment: It's built-in with `syslogd`. There's also `syslog-ng`, or whatever other replacement logging facility you like. Auditing certain file/system events is specific to what you want to monitor.  All that said, product recommendations are off-topic on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [KidLogger](http://kidlogger.net/)  Application for this. It will log all user activities. You can create a cron to copy logs generated by KidLogger  to local server.

[Download KidLogger](http://kidlogger.net/)